# How to select specific columns for multiple dataframes using a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiple-columns

I am trying to select only certain columns from a number of different dataframes using a for loop. In the for loop, the print(df.shape) gives me the expected results. However, when I check the results after the for loop has completed, no changes were made to the dataframes.

I have the following dataframes:

```
data = { 'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick', 'Joe']
        ,'Age': [20, 21, 19]
        ,'Color': ['blue', 'pink', 'orange']}

puppy_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = { 'Name': ['Ann', 'Jill', 'Abby']
        ,'Age': [33, 44, 55]
        ,'Color': ['teal', 'red', 'green']}

kitty_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to only select the columns 'Name' and 'Color' from each dataframe using a for loop:

```
my_list = [puppy_df, kitty_df]

for i in my_list:
    i = i[['Name','Color']]
    print(i.shape)
```

The for loop prints the expected results for shape (3,2) for each dataframe.  However, when I check the dataframe, the changes were not applied.

Comment: `i.drop(columns=columns_to_drop,in_place=True)` might be what you want

Comment: thanks Joran.  This is a basic example.  i have a lot of mismatching columns among the different dataframes.  so i want to specify the ones that i want to keep, instead of dropping them.

Comment: the ones you want to drop are `columns=[c for c in df.columns if c is not in columns_to_keep]`